# A property of convex functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The question is that:

Prove or Disprove: Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous, if 
$$\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R},\exists \epsilon \in ]0, 1[, f(x+(1-\epsilon)y)\le f(x)+(1-\epsilon)f(y)$$, then $f$ is convex...

I just have no idea how to use the condtion that it's continuous to make $\exists$ into $\forall$...

Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 0):

Note that the usual notion of convex has the inequality the other way.

One expects convexity to be a geometric notion, so it should be invariant by translations; but your definition isn't: a function satisfying your property will fail it if we add of subtract an appropriate constant. So it cannot be convexity. It would look a lot like convexity if it would have been
$$
f(\epsilon x+(1-\epsilon)y)\leq \epsilon f(x)+(1-\epsilon)f(y).
$$

Comment: You are right. I've mistyped the notion. But how to derive for all epsilon, the inequality holds?